# Testing few methods for correct validation of passed argument

Tags: phpunit

I have few methods witch takes the same argument (user_id). In these methods I test passed argument for valid eight numbers integer.
Is there possibility any to group(?) test(s) for testing validation of passed argument?

```
Class Hello{
public function test($user_id=0){
 if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}$/', $user_id)) return false;
do stuff...
}
public function make($user_id=0){
 if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}$/', $user_id)) return false;
do stuff...
}
public function find($user_id=0){
 if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}$/', $user_id)) return false;
do stuff...
}
}
```

and test file:

```
class HelloTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

//Looking for something simpler to replace that:
        // zwraca FALSE jesli dlugosc inna niz 8 znakow 
        $this->assertFalse(Hello::test('1'), 'Dlugosc user_id musi byc 8 znakow, nie 1.');
        $this->assertFalse(Hello::test(0), 'Dlugosc user_id musi byc 8 znakow, nie 1 (zero).');
        $this->assertFalse(Hello::test('7777777'), 'Dlugosc user_id musi byc 8 znakow, nie 7.');

        $this->assertFalse(Hello::make('1'), 'Dlugosc user_id musi byc 8 znakow, nie 1.');
        $this->assertFalse(Hello::make(0), 'Dlugosc user_id musi byc 8 znakow, nie 1 (zero).');
        $this->assertFalse(Hello::make('7777777'), 'Dlugosc user_id musi byc 8 znakow, nie 7.');

        $this->assertFalse(Hello::find('1'), 'Dlugosc user_id musi byc 8 znakow, nie 1.');
        $this->assertFalse(Hello::find(0), 'Dlugosc user_id musi byc 8 znakow, nie 1 (zero).');
        $this->assertFalse(Hello::find('7777777'), 'Dlugosc user_id musi byc 8 znakow, nie 7.');
}
```

Comment: Did you get a satisfactory answer from anyone to accept, or is there still issues with the suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [PHPUnit Manual, under Data Providers](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers) you can use a Data Provider to pass values to a test.  I do this, and include the expected response value.

```
<?php
class HelloTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function UserIdDataProvider()
    {
        return array(
            array('1', FALSE, 'Dlugosc user_id musi byc 8 znakow, nie 1.'),
            array(0, FALSE, 'Dlugosc user_id musi byc 8 znakow, nie 1 (zero).'),
            array('7777777', FALSE, 'Dlugosc user_id musi byc 8 znakow, nie 7.'),
            array('88888888', TRUE, ''),
        );
    }

     /**
     * @dataProvider UserIdDataProvider
     */
    public function testUserIdTest($UserId, $Result, $Message)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($Result, Hello::test($UserId), $Message);
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider UserIdDataProvider
     */
    public function testUserMake($UserId, $Result, $Message)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($Result, Hello::make($UserId), $Message);
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider UserIdDataProvider
     */
    public function testUserIdFind($UserId, $Result, $Message)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($Result, Hello::find($UserId), $Message);
    }

}
?>
```